# I cannot lock the tables, previously it was working

Tags: mysql

I am new to locking mysql table, I had some issues if I am not using lock tables

I am running the following command in heidisql

```
LOCK TABLES image_questions
```

it throws the following error:

SQL Error(1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax....

I am uploading some images to choices column in image_questions table.

I am serializing array with images and storing the images to choices column, I am uploading using dropzone, I had some issues without locking the tables

Comment: The reason for locking a table a few, if you show some context a lockless solution maybe your answer. Also with MySQL errors showing the full error gives a clue as to what might be incorrect.

Comment: @danblack I have edited the question I am updating column reading and writing

Comment: What issues did you have?

Answer (score 0):

The lock tables syntax error is that `LOCK TABLES` requires a lock type.

As per the syntax in the [manual for lock tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html).

```
LOCK TABLES image_questions WRITE
```

Comment: But I used this before, it was working fine, now I feel like somebody changed something, so it is not working...

Comment: Suggest loading a new table and then using a `RENAME TABLE original TO old, new TO original`  to swap out the old table and replace with the new.